# How to set default values in ng-select in angular6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, multi-select, angular-ngselect

I am using angular6 `multi-select` which have a list of items coming in an array of objects from angular service on `ngOnInit` like this which is passing into `multi-select` :

```
this.sensorTypes = [
  { label : "Power", value : "P"},
  { label : "Current", value : "C"},
  { label : "Voltage", value : "V"}
]
```

I want to set 2 values by default in `multi-select` when form will load. For this i am binding `ngModel` on `multi-select`and in that variable i am setting values on `ngOnInit` like this

```
this.selectedAttributes = [
  {label : "Current", value : "C"},
  {label : "Voltage", value : "V"}
]
```

In my component.html i am creating `multi-select` like this :

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <ng-select 
       [ngClass]="'ng-select'" 
       [(ngModel)]="selectedAttributes" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
       [options]="sensorTypes"
       [multiple]="true">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But values are not setting by default in multi-select.

Comment: you can do something like this in `ngOnInit` or any of life cycle like this : `this.selectedAttributes = this.sensorTypes[0]`, if `sensorTypes` is `array` of `objects`

Comment: why i need to do this when i am binding ngModel having values in it?

Comment: can you please post StackBlitz

Comment: let me create stackBlitz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `[items]` input binding instead of `[options]`

```
<ng-select 
  [items]="sensorTypes"
  bindLabel="label"                 
  [multiple]="true"
  placeholder="Select"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedAttributes">
</ng-select>
```

And on your component's module.ts, import the `NgSelectModule`. And if you haven't import your `FormsModule`, you should do so, as it needs to be imported for 2 way binding with `ngModel` to work.

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
.
.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
. 
.
.
```

Comment: but the list shows correctly in angular multi select when i open drop down. then only problem is that i cna't set default values dynamically.

Comment: Hmm.. But according to the ng-select documentations (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select), there is not such binding for `[options]`. I think you are required to use `[items]` in order for it to work

Comment: I have edited my solution; added `bindLabel`. Do you wanna try copying and pasting my code and see if it works?

Comment: yes it is throwing an error like this

`Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'.`

Comment: Oh.. Are you using an older version of ng-select?

Comment: i am using this version `"ng-select": "^1.0.1"`

Comment: Ok, did you `import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';` and `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'` onto your component module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188790/discussion-between-fahad-hassan-subzwari-and-wentjun).

Answer (score 4):

if you are using both bindlabel and bindvalue so fist find index of selected value t
e

```
var index= this.sensorTypes.findIndex(x => x.ID ==something); 
//this will set value
this.selectedAttributes= this.sensorTypes[index].ID;
```

Comment: This is the answer helped me, since i'm using both bind value and bind label. For people who don't understand -> You have to bind the value you given as bindValue as the value, not the bindLabel value

Answer (score 3):

> values are not setting by default in multi-select

for this assign `this.sensorTypes[0]` to ngModel of your `ng-select` in `ngOnInit()`

```js
    ngOnInit() {
      this.selectedAttributes = this.sensorTypes[0]
    }
```

this will get the first attribute as the default one.

Comment: what if i have to set multiple values in ng-select by defailt?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ng-select modules:

- `@ng-select/ng-select`
- `ng-select`

both directive tags are same and [options] used in ng-select and [items] used in `@ng-select/ng-select`

ng-select documentation https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select/#/documentation

Its all your choice to use any of one